# data has been messed up after loading parquet from hdfs using spark

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, corruption

I had some text files on hdfs cluster. After that I load these text files using spark and rewrite them on hdfs using parquet format and remove those text files.

```
df = spark.read.text(hdfs_url)
df.coalesce(partition_num).write.option("compression","gzip").parquet(new_hdfs_url)
```

Now, when I load these parquet files using spark, my data messed up and I don't have any idea what's the problem with them.

```
df = spark.read.parquet(new_hdfs_url)
```

my real data are some nginx error logs, but when I take data, I see something like this:

```
'PAR1\x15\x00\x15���\x01\x15��\x0b,\x15�\x1e\x15\x00\x15\x06\x15\x08\x1c6\x00(�\x052019-10-28T20:54:58.369Z "PUBLIC.STH.COM"  2019/10/29 00:24:58 [error] 15643#15643: *111716990 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 5.12.123.4, server: s1.something.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/", upstream: "http://5.5.5.5:80/", host: "s1.something.com", referrer: "http://something.com/?fbclid=IwAR0Ywsy-U2XFit1u3ITn4RmPfP_WnNmRcG2_70iK_8JXyr1D4" 35825232e44d1da669b7d4:\x18�\x032019-10-28T02:07:23.144Z "PUBLIC.SOMETHING.COM"  2019/10/28 05:37:23 [error] 15546#15546: *107839350 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.123.123.123, server: something.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://5.5.5.15:80/", host: "s1.something.com" 825ed3d1dad1481705d4:\x00\x00\x00\x1f�\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00�k�$Yv\x1eFia�\t\t\x12)�\x12E�8�"v�\x1b�����j��U�ݻ��î���Y/�Q�QU9��Q����\u0604a\x014d)�\x06�ǆe��a\x10�?��Eل�_$`ِa'
```

One of my guesses is incorrect load of data, because in this data, I have two seperate logs in one record but in some of these records there is nothing as a data like this:

```
�-��\x00A�!
```

Comment: Does it work after the first `spark.read.text(hdfs_url)`? E.g. what does `spark.read.text(hdfs_url).show()` give you?

Comment: My understanding is that if you compress a parquet file with gzip yourself, it won't be a parquet file anymore.

Comment: @thebluephantom While that is true, spark can use the `gzip` compression without it being a `gz` file, which is what is happening here. But as you say, if you save it as `gzip` yourself it's not a parquet file anymore.

Comment: I just tried on databricks and no issues found.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman it shows something like this output

Comment: @thebluephantom hmm, do you think there is any method to revert this problem(it's a guess and I want to check it), although I checked this method on some other of my files and I don't have any problem with them, one of my guesses is something like this: I have text file, read this text file as parquet and after that save them as parquet

Comment: Not sure what to make of it. You need to read parquet as parquet.

Comment: I suspect this is a encoding issue. Try adding the encoding options on your reading:
`spark.read.option("encoding", "UTF-8").text(hdfs_url)`.

Comment: Try to make it do an RDD instead of dataframe by using `sc.textFile` (in stead of `spark.read.text`) and see how it turns out?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman no, unfortunately neither works

Comment: Have you tried opening it (or parts of it) in a text editor or something?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman no, how can I do that, is there any text editor supports hdfs?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman and also I thought spark.read.text do the same thing

Comment: this link https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Cannot-read-Parquet-format-generated-by-Spark/td-p/22539 say something about wrong table format but it corrects using hive table

Comment: But you are not able to read the raw log (even before you turn it into parquet). So I think you want to start there. `sc.TextFile` reads it into an RDD, while `spark.read.text` attempts to process the RDD, I believe.